# Progress Bar increments at twice the intended speed each time

Tags: vb.net, button, timer, progress-bar

```
Private Time As New Timer

Private Sub btnWood_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnWood.Click


    prgWood.Value = 0

    Time.Interval = 1000
    Time.Start()
    AddHandler Time.Tick, AddressOf IncreaseProgressBar

    If prgWood.Value <> prgWood.Maximum Then
        btnWood.Enabled = False
    End If

    Dim intAmountofWood As Integer = 11 * Rnd() + 10
    intWood = intWood + intAmountofWood

    Me.lblWoodAmount.Text = intWood

Private Sub IncreaseProgressBar(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    prgWood.Increment(10)

    If prgWood.Value = prgWood.Maximum Then
        prgWood.Increment(0)
        Time.Stop()
        btnWood.Enabled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

For my progress bar, I use a Timer to increment the value by 10 every 1 second. When I debug the project, it works fine the first time (taking 10 seconds for the progress bar to complete) but when I click the button a second time, it only takes 5 seconds, then less and less each time. This code is for an incremental game I'm trying to make for school.

Comment: Only add the AddHandler once in the constructor.  You are adding it every time, which means your Tick event is being called multiple times every time you start it.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks for answering, how would I get rid of the AddHandler while still associating the timer with my progress bar? Sorry, I'm still pretty new to vb.

Answer (score 1):

From LarsTech's comment:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Time As New Timer

    Public Sub New()
        'Initialisation, etc

        AddHandler Time.Tick, AddressOf IncreaseProgressBar
    End Sub

    'Other methods, etc
End Class
```

Then you need to remove the `AddHandler` from the button 
click event

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this?

Create a `sub` and add this code

`

```
ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
    ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Minimum
End If
```

`

then call that sub here.

```
`Private Sub btnWood_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnWood.Click

    '**Name of the Sub**
    prgWood.Value = 0

    Time.Interval = 1000
    Time.Start()
    AddHandler Time.Tick, AddressOf IncreaseProgressBar

    If prgWood.Value <> prgWood.Maximum Then
        btnWood.Enabled = False
    End If

    Dim intAmountofWood As Integer = 11 * Rnd() + 10
    intWood = intWood + intAmountofWood

    Me.lblWoodAmount.Text = intWood

End Sub
`
```

let see if that one works